# using LLVM-C api from MSYS2 returns exit code 1, but using WSL works fine

Tags: c++, c, llvm

i installed llvm+clang using MSYS2, and all the tools work fine for me, but the LLVM-C always returns exit code 1, here is my sample code:

```c
#include <llvm-c/Core.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    LLVMModuleRef mod = LLVMModuleCreateWithName("my_module");

    LLVMPrintModuleToFile(mod, "my_module.ll", NULL);

    LLVMDisposeModule(mod);
    return 0;
}
```

it compiles on MSYS2, but it returns exit code 1, and does not write the module to the file,

but when compiled using WSL, it returns exit code 0 and writes to the file.

i am using these MSYS2 packages:
https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-clang?repo=mingw64 
https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-llvm?repo=mingw64

i did not try the C++ LLVM api, but i am assuming that does not work as well.

here are the commands i run:
powershell:

```
$x = llvm-config --cflags --ldflags core --system-libs --libs
clang $x hello.c -fuse-ld=lld
./a.exe
echo $lastExitCode # returns 1
```

bash:

```sh
clang `llvm-config --cflags --ldflags core --system-libs --libs` hello.c
./a.out
cat my_module.ll
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with powershell. Does it put _all_ the args into `x`? What happens if you paste in the final args directly into the `clang` command? Can you run the `a.out` under a debugger?

Comment: yes, it puts all the args into x, and i do not know how to use a debugger, i will try to use gdb though.

Comment: i found that bug was on line 5, on the creation of the module, it returns code '0xc0000139', aka, -1073741511.

Comment: And what does our research on this Windows error code reveal?

Comment: i don't know, all i know is that it returns that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nvm i fixed it, my solution is that instead of using powershell, i used the MSYS2 (MinGW-w64) shell.